# Make field's queryset from cleaned_data

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-forms, django-formwizard

How can you make a `queryset` or a `list` from cleaned data without accessing the database?
I'm using Django 1.5 `FormWizard` and `ModelFormSet` here. The following doesn't work with the error:

> 'list' object has no attribute 'all'

That means you can't use a list, can you?

```
def get_form(self, step=None, data=None, files=None):
    form = super(MyWizard, self).get_form(step=step, data=data, files=files)
    #...
    data = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('a')
    list = []
    for item in data:
        list.append(item['car']) # This is the choice of a ForeigenKey
    #...
    form.fields['name'].queryset = list
```

This is working but it seems to me that you do the work twice:

```
def get_form(self, step=None, data=None, files=None):
    form = super(MyWizard, self).get_form(step=step, data=data, files=files)
    #...
    data = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('a')
    list = []
    for item in data:
        list.append(item['car'].id) # This is the choice of a ForeigenKey
    #...
    form.fields['name'].queryset = SomeClass.objects.filter(pk__in=list)
```

So is there a way around?

Comment: Very confused - cleaned data comes from POSting a form, and the queryset is used to populate the model form in the GET request. What is the workflow for this code being run?

Comment: @professorDante The cleaned data comes from the previous step of a form wizard.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a list in place of a queryset, you have to assign a queryset to the fields queryset attribute, hence the first error. You have to hit the DB to make the queryset, so I'm not sure what you're asking. You could improve the code by using a list comp:

```
my_list = [item['car'].id for item in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can post your form declaration, but it seems that `name` is a `ModelChoiceField`, and thus requires a queryset. You could convert it to a simple `ChoiceField`, but you would have to build the `choices`:

```
form.fields['name'].choices = [(item['car'].id, unicode(item['car'])] for item in data]
```

However, I'm not sure if this would save automatically, in case this is a `ModelForm`, but then again, we would need the form declaration to tell.